# Front end free CMS? (Or CMF)

Tags: php, content-management-system

Can anybody point me in the direction of a good CMS system which is not packaged with a front end (Content management framework)?

Ultimately I'd like some kind of CMS framework - a full administration suite which outputs content to XML or something similar so that we can build the front end from scratch.

Usually we would build a bespoke system for something like this, however the client has specifically asked for an existing open source solution.

Do Drupal or Joomla have 'stripped down' versions which might fulfill my criteria? Or some kind of plugins that anybody knows of?

Hope I have explained this clearly enough. AppRain (http://www.apprain.com/) is the closest i've found to what i'm looking for, but I'm concerned it's lacking in documentation and support.

Thanks for any help...

Comment: of course, you could always write a bespoke solution and release it as open source....  ;-)

Comment: We at Army.mil couldn't find one 2 years ago. We had to build our own.

Comment: Seems like there is a gap in the market for this kind of solution! appRain is very interesting, will keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're up for it, try [typo3](http://typo3.org/). A word of advice, though: **it's loaded**.

You can fully design your frontend, there's actually no limitations. However, typo3 is extremely hungry! Anything less than a `memory_limit` of 256 MB will not suffice.

Comment: Cheers mate, going to have a read up on it now, however I am a little put off by that kind of resource usage. The front end of the project has to be build in Zend so I could end up with a real monster!

Comment: If that's the requirement, go on and build that monstrosity. Don't think, it's going to run on a shared hosting environment, though...

Answer (score 1):

You can theme Drupal and WordPress to output data in any format you choose.

They are not necessarily the *best* solution for outputting data in different formats, as they are tailored towards HTML specifically.

Comment: I might check out Drupal. I hear good things about it a lot of the time, I find the interface a little ugly when I've tested it on opensourcecms.com, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @baz, agreed, but the interface is fully customizable. Just specify a new admin theme.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using **[SPIP](http://www.spip.net/en)** for years. Pretty lightweight and easy to use and implement.

It's not loaded by default with a bunch of plugins/extensions you won't use. It's a pure Content Management System.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SilverStripe CMS

http://silverstripe.org/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, bloated content management systems like Joomla or Drupal are terrible for the end-user experience and not very developer friendly. Concrete5 is a powerful CMS that is easy for developers and even easier for end-users. It works on a in-context editing model so you make changes as you're browsing your site. If you're tired of long training sessions and tons of client support requests, try a demo of Concrete5 here: http://bit.ly/concrete5cms

Answer (score 0):

I think is kind 1 year too late and nobody watches this thread, anyway, you should try aws xms:  http://www.aws-dms.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess what the questioner (baz) means is an ultimate decoupling between the logic and the frontend, and the only intermediate layer is an xml file.

So then inside the template the xml could be available as an object, and you could call each element like this:

```
<?php echo $xml->header->title ?>
```

I do not know if something like this exists, I think there are some hurdles to take here, but it would definitely be a nice solution. Anyone?

I have chosen a similar direction, but instead of getting the data ready as an xml, it works the other way around. The template defines new elements on the page, and the 'engine' reads that and stores the data on the appropriate place. I used this approach for a Wordpress plugin that enables the website to be edited entirely in the front-end.

For those who are interested, look at http://frontendcms.com. Be warned, I did not publish it as open source. But I would be happy to share some ideas if you are interested.